# Dynamic form field configuration in mvc

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, dynamic, configuration, field

I have multiple employee groups in my project. Based on the selection of different employee group,submission form fields will differ in the view. If the fields are static then it is easy to do the CRUD operations. I need to create the fields dynamic in nature. I must be able to configure the form fields in SQL server table.For employee Group 1, 5 fields, for Group 2, 6 fields etc. If i want to add new field to any of the group in future also it should work. How can i achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using many-to-many relationship between tables `Employees` and `Fields`. Something like this:

[image: database scheme]

You'll have a table that holds the list of all possible fields (first name, last name and etc). Then to connect the `Employees` table and the `Fields` table with many-to-many relationship you'll need some kind of table (`EmployeesFields`). Table `EmployeesFields` holds the value for the each field that employee has.

For example:

```
EMPLOYEES
+----+------------------+
| Id |    CreatedAt     |
+----+------------------+
|  1 | 02.08.2017 11:21 |
+----+------------------+


FIELDS
+----+-----------+------------------+
| Id |   Name    |    CreatedAt     |
+----+-----------+------------------+
|  1 | FirstName | 02.08.2017 11:24 |
|  2 | LastName  | 02.08.2017 11:26 |
+----+-----------+------------------+


EMPLOYEESFIELDS
+------------+---------+-------+------------------+
| EmployeeId | FieldId | Value |    CreatedAt     |
+------------+---------+-------+------------------+
|          1 |       1 | John  | 02.08.2017 11:34 |
|          1 |       2 | Doe   | 02.08.2017 11:39 |
+------------+---------+-------+------------------+
```

I think this is the most simple solution. It just shows the basic idea. Modify it to fit your needs.